# Unable to get ValidationTechnicalProfile to valid input

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to setup the use of a one time pass code (OTP) on an Azure B2C Custom Policy.  I have a working set of `Orchestration` steps that extract an email from a claims token supplied in the URL and then mail a randomly generated code to that email.  I know there are "`VerifyCode`" and "`GenerateCode`" technical profiles available, but they rely on the user entering the email into a display field first, which I want to avoid.

I am unable get a `ValidationTechnicalProfile` to fire so that it can execute a `ClaimsTransformation` to the two claims values.  These are the generated OTP mailed to the user and the input collected from a `TechnicalProvider` that uses a `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` to display the input field with a `ContentDefinition`.

I am basing my code on this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations) and also a walkthrough with regard to [ValidationTechnicalProfiles](https://www.atmosera.com/blog/hello-world-and-then-some-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-policies-part-4-hello-but-only-if-you-have-an-access-code)

Please could someone explain why the `ValidationTechnicalProfile` appears to either be skipped or is failing to work?

**Claims**

```xml
<ClaimType Id="Otp">
  <DisplayName>One-time password</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
<ClaimType Id="VerificationCode">
  <DisplayName>Secondary Verification Code</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserHelpText>Enter your verification code</UserHelpText>
  <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

**Orchestration Step**

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
   <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-OTP-Exchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-EnterOTP" />
   </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

**Technical Profile**

Uses the api.page.codeinput content definition to collect the value of the `VerificationCode` claim in an input box.  Once collected, it should fire the `Self-AssertedOTPCompare` `TechnicalProfile` as a `ValidationTechnicalProfile`

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EnterOTP">
 <DisplayName>Enter OTP</DisplayName>
 <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
 <Metadata>
   <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.page.codeinput</Item>
   <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">Invalid OTP Code</Item>
 </Metadata>
 <OutputClaims>
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
 </OutputClaims>
 <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Self-AssertedOTPCompare" />
 </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**Validation Technical Profile**

Executes the `AssertSuppliedAndGeneratedOTPAreEqual` `ClaimsTransformation`

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="Self-AssertedOTPCompare">
  <DisplayName>Returns the result from comparing the generated OTP with the supplied on</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertSuppliedAndGeneratedOTPAreEqual" />
  </OutputClaimsTransformations>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

**Claims Transformation**

Should compare the two claims and raise an exception to prevent the user continuing if the codes are different.

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AssertSuppliedAndGeneratedOTPAreEqual" TransformationMethod="AssertStringClaimsAreEqual">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Otp" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="VerificationCode" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="stringComparison" DataType="string" Value="ordinalIgnoreCase" />
  </InputParameters>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Logging with AppInsights I think it's hitting the technical profile but control appears to be returning to the orchestration.  If I remove the `ValidationTechnicalProfiles` section from the `SelfAsserted-EnterOTP` technical profile, the flow stops at the page where the user would enter their code.

```json
 {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true,
      "RecorderRecord": {
        "Values": [
          {
            "Key": "InitiatingClaimsExchange",
            "Value": {
              "ProtocolType": "Identity Experience Engine API",
              "TargetEntity": "Generate-OTP",
              "TechnicalProfileId": "SelfAsserted-EnterOTP",
              "ProtocolProviderType": "SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "PredicateResult": "True"
    }
  }, 
  {
    "Kind": "Action",
    "Content": "Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.SwitchToApiOrchestrationHandler"
  },
  {
    "Kind": "HandlerResult",
    "Content": {
      "Result": true
    }
  },
  {
    "Kind": "Transition",
    "Content": {
      "EventName": "SELFASSERTED",
      "StateName": "AwaitingNextStep"
    }
  },
```

**Additional**

The original implementation above caused the process to never show the input field to collect the OTP from the user - [jas-suri-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft) suggests this is because a `ValidationTechnicalProvider` does not bubble up exceptions.

If this is the case, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations) appears to be wrong:

> The AssertStringClaimsAreEqual claims transformation is always
> executed from a validation technical profile that is called by a
> self-asserted technical profile, or a DisplayControl. The
> UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual metadata of a
> self-asserted technical profile controls the error message that is
> presented to the user.

I have tried changing the `ValidationTechnicalProfiles` to a `OutputClaimsTransformations` node as suggested.

I replaced this:

```xml
 <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Self-AssertedOTPCompare" />
 </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
```

with this:

```xml
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
  <OutputClaimsTransformation 
 ReferenceId="AssertSuppliedAndGeneratedOTPAreEqual" />
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

This caused the OTP collection screen to show but the page to show no error message if the code was wrong and go no further.  This is despite setting `UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual` in the metadata However, entering the correct code allowed the steps to progress.

So how to do I get the page to show the exception message?

**SOLUTION**

As mentioned in the comments, I am unable to remove the OutputClaims from the `ValidationTechnicalProfile` as the policy will not validate.  However, changing the `OutputClaim` to a `DisplayClaim` resolves the issue.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-EnterOTP">
  <DisplayName>Enter OTP</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.page.codeinput</Item>
    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">Invalid OTP Code</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <DisplayClaims>
    <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="suppliedOTP" Required="true" />
  </DisplayClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="Self-AssertedOTPCompare" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a claims transformation technical profile from the validation technical profile section, the error is not bubbled up like when called directly as an `OutputClaimsTransformation`. So i suspect your observation is that, any code entered works and proceeds to the next step in the journey.

Instead, call `AssertSuppliedAndGeneratedOTPAreEqual` as an `OutputClaimsTransformation` directly from `SelfAsserted-EnterOTP`.

Comment: I have tried the above, not entirely successful, please review "Additional" above

Comment: So it does look like what your original solution was should work. The reason the field doesn’t appear is because you have it as an output in the validation technical profile. Remove the output claim there, or use a displayclaim instead of an output claim in the self asserted technical profile.

Comment: Apparently not - I tried your suggestion and got a validation error - "The OutputClaims for TechnicalProfile "Self-AssertedOTPCompare" with ClaimsTransformation Protocol type in policy <policyName> and tenant <tenantName> should not be null or empty"

Comment: However, it looks like your second suggestion of adding a DisplayClaim works. Just testing.

Comment: Original question updated with solution